# Converting Iterable[(Double, Double)] to Seq(Seq(Double))

Tags: scala, rdd, iterable, seq

I want to convert Pair RDD "myRDD" values from Iterable[(Double,Double)] to Seq(Seq(Double)), however I am not sure how to do it. I tried the following but it does not work.

```
val groupedrdd: RDD[BB,Iterable[(Double,Double)]] = RDDofPoints.groupByKey()
val RDDofSeq = groupedrdd.mapValues{case (x,y) => Seq(x,y)}
```

The myRDD is formed using a groupByKey operation on a RddofPoints with their respective bounding boxes as keys. The BB is a case class and it is the key for a set of points with type (Double,Double). I want the RDDofSeq to have the type RDD[BB,Seq(Seq(Double))], however after groupByKey, myRDD has the type RDD[BB,Iterable[(Double,Double)]].

Here, it gives an error as:

```
Error:(107, 58) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: Iterable[(Double, Double)]
```

I am new to Scala, any help in this regard is appreciated. Thanks.

**ANSWER** : The following is used to accomplish the above goal:

```
val RDDofSeq = groupedrdd.mapValues{iterable => iterable.toSeq.map{case (x,y) => Seq(x,y)}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried this on [Scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/X2M20RS/0)

```
val myRDD: Iterable[(Double,Double)] = Seq((1.1, 1.2), (2.1, 2.2))

val RDDofSeq = myRDD.map{case (x,y) => Seq(x,y)}

println(RDDofSeq) // returns List(List(1.1, 1.2), List(2.1, 2.2))
```

The only difference is that I used `myRDD.map(..` instead of `myRDD.mapValues(..`

Make sure that `myRDD` is really of the type `Iterable[(Double,Double)]`!

**Update after comment:**

If I understand you correctly you want a `Seq[Double]` and not a `Seq[Seq[Double]]`

That would be this:

```
val RDDofSeq = myRDD.map{case (k,v) => v} // returns List(1.2, 2.2)
```

**Update after the Type is now clear:**

The values are of type `Iterable[(Double,Double)]` so you cannot match on a pair.

Try this:

```
 val RDDofSeq = groupedrdd.mapValues{iterable => 
 Seq(iterable.head._1, iterable.head._2)}
```

Comment: Nice answer! You could even include a link to the documentation of map and mapValues. I think the main thing is that mapValues actually returns a map (if I remember correctly) while map...maps the values/elements

Comment: actually `mapValues` is not available for `Iterable` - which I think is the problem (`myRDD` is not the type that user331676 expects)

Comment: seems you're right. Here's the documentation https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Iterable.html  can't find it anywhere. There is a function called toSeq though :)

Comment: Thanks @pme, but the problem is I have a pair rdd (K,V), and I only want to convert the values in a Sequence. When I use just map, it makes a sequence of the keys with values.

Comment: @user3316676 see my adjusted answer

Comment: Actually the values are in the form Iterable[(Double, Double)] as mentioned in the question, and I want to convert values to Seq(Seq(Double)). So, the resulting RDD should be of the type [(Key type), Seq(Seq(Double))].

Comment: @user3316676 please add thre types to your question:

`myRRD:YourType ` and  `val RDDofSeq: YourType = myRDD.mapValues{case (x: YourType, y: YourType) => Seq(x ,y)}`

Comment: I added the type of myRDD and RDDofSeq in question. I do not know how to give the type of x and y individually; they are a group of points with type Iterable[(Double,Double)]. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't see the type of `val groupedrdd = RDDofPoints.groupByKey()`  and how it's related to `myRDD`?

Comment: Sorry, I did not change the name of groupedrdd as myRDD. The groupedrdd actually is the result of groupByKey() on RDDofPoints and its type is RDD[BB,Iterable[(Double,Double)]]. I want to convert only the values of groupedrdd to Seq(Seq(Double)). So the resulting rdd RDDofSeq has the type RDD[BB,Seq(Seq(Double))].

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. I tried the update after type is clear, but it is giving an error on y "Cannot resolve symbol y".

Comment: sorry my fault - I adjusted my answer

Comment: It took only the first elements of Iterable using val RDDofSeq = groupedrdd.mapValues{iterable => 
 Seq(iterable.head._1, iterable.head._2)}. I figured out a way to do it (see updated question), thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You just need `map`, not `mapValues`.

```
val RDDofSeq = myRDD.map{case (x,y) => Seq(x,y)}
```